# Is there a way to automatically link all libraries an OpenGL program needs, without explicitly writing their flags on compile?

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

For an entry level program, I'm currently compiling with

`g++ manip.c -o manip -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor -lGLEW`

It was a very time-consuming process of trial and error figuring out which flags were necessary, googling the 'undefined references to', copy pasting every flag I came across and then deleting flags one by one until I had removed those I didn't need.

For a beginner who is learning the ropes, compiling example programs in tutorials (that don't have instructions on how to compile), is there a way to automatically link everything the program might need? Perhaps a way to move the libraries so they don't have to be explicitly linked?

If not, is there a way to simplify the flag adding process? (I can envisage the command becoming incredibly long from all the flags as the program grows in complexity.)

Comment: Learn how to use makefiles or a makefile generator like cmake

Comment: You should look into actual build systems, rather than writing command lines manually.

Comment: `g++ manip.c -o manip \`pkg-config glfw3 glew --cflags --libs\``?

Comment: @genpfault: [Upstream manual](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html#build_link_pkgconfig) indeed recommends `pkg-config` if you're not using a metabuild-system like CMake.

Comment: When I use the command you pasted, genpfault, and also the static and shared commands in the Upstream manual you linked, TBBle, hundreds? of undefined references errors result.

Comment: You probably need CMake with config headers. The first one to find the library and the second to name it depending on the system (`#ifdef __APPLE__ #include <dir1/lib1> #else #include <dir2/lib1> #elif`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer for someone at the level I'm at.

You apparently can write makefiles that will automatically detect what libraries should be linked. The syntax for doing so is way out of my depths, but I'll edit this in future if I advance to that.

To simplify the compiling option, you could write a makefile that links every single library you might need. The example I've included below has the libraries I've found out I require so far and may need to be extended significantly as I develop the OpenGL program further.

Call the file 'Makefile'. Run it using the command `make`.

So
`vim Makefile`

Inside the file, I have this:

```
manip: manip.c
        g++ manip.c -o manip -lglfw3 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -ldl -lXinerama -lXcursor -lGLEW -lglfw3 -lGL -lm -lXi
```

The term before the `:` on the first line will be the output executable. The term after the `:` on the first line is the C/C++ file the executable depends on. The next line is what the Makefile will execute if it detects the source code (after `:` on the first line) has changed.

If you have a more extensive set of files that depend on each other, you can add them below with the same syntax (google this if relevant to you).

So I now edit the `manip.c` file, run the command `make`, and `manip` is generated for me.

Comment: Just FYI: It really boils down to the linker and how the other libraries being used have been linked themself. With a modern linker (e.g. on my system currently GNU ld 2.25) and shared objects linked with that, indirect dependencies get pulled in automatically and you can write something as simple as `g++ -o … -lGL -lGLEW -lglfw` and all the rest gets pulled in automatically.

Comment: I tried just a few flags, including those main ones, initially, but there were undefined references. Is there one flag that pulls in all the libraries with -lX... beginnings?

Comment: It's not a matter of flags (there is no magic flag that automatically pulls all dependencies). It's a matter of which particular build of toolchain and libraries you use. If you use a Linux distribution where "everything" was stripped of shared objects and/or the installed toolchain lacks the functions required, there's little you can do. That's why things like `pkg-config` came to existence in the first place. You didn't specify which particular Linux distribution you use. Debian for instance often is terribly outdated compared with upstream versions of tools and libs.